# Swing Graphics on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Using Java Graphics, I tried to draw a simple rectangle.

As `Applet` it runs well but when I use it to show on a `JFrame`, the rectangle is coming but with some unusual background

Here is coding:

```
package graphicsex;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Graphics2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graphics2 inst = new Graphics2();
        inst.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Graphics2() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            pack();
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(10, 20, 30, 40);
    }
}
```

Then I tried to use `JTextArea` using these two classes but in this case the rectangle is not displaying at all.

```
GraphicsEx1.java:

package graphicsex;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GraphicsEx1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JTextArea jTextArea1;

    {
        //Set Look & Feel
        try {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEx1 inst = new GraphicsEx1();
        inst.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GraphicsEx1() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            {
                jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
                getContentPane().add(jTextArea1);
                jTextArea1.setBounds(7, 7, 371, 245);
                jTextArea1.setEnabled(false);
            }
            pack();
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        postInitGUI();
    }

    public void postInitGUI() {
        DisplayItems dp = new DisplayItems();
        jTextArea1 = dp;
        dp.setVisible(true);
        this.add(jTextArea1);
    }
}
```

And DisplayItems.java:

```
package graphicsex;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DisplayItems extends javax.swing.JTextArea {

    public DisplayItems() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(10, 20, 50, 100);
        g.drawString("Kalai", 90, 150);
    }
}
```

Can any one help me display graphics components on any swing containers like `JFrame,`JPanel`or`JTextarea` etc.

Answer (score 4):

It is inadvisable to override the `paint` method of a top level container...

`JFrame` contains a number of important layers onto which many other components are placed, buy doing this...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawRect(10,20,30,40);
}
```

You've successfully stopped any of the child components from begin painted, or in fact, anything other then your rectangle.

[image]

*(The secret life of a top level swing container - Picture taken from [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html))*

While some might suggest simple adding a call to `super.paint(g)`, I would not recommend it.

Better to use something like the `JFrame`'s glass pane...This will allow you to paint over the components that reside within the frame.  If you need to paint under the components, replace the `JFrame`'s content pane instead.

You may find...

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Of use...

**Update**

I think I'm beginning to see you problem with trying to perform custom painting on a text area.

The problem is, `paintComponent` paints the background AND the text in one foul swoop, meaning that any painting you do before calling `super.paintComponent` will be rendered over, but any painting done over it will paint over the text.

You could set the text area to be non-opaque and paint the background yourself...

[image]

```
public class CustomTextArea extends JTextArea {

    public CustomTextArea() {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

}
```

The problem is though, it's easy for people to rest the opaque level and destroy your work.  Sure you could override the `setOpaque` or `getOpaque`, but how do you known when the user actually wants to set the component transparent, so you can stop fill the back ground?

Comment: Thanks for your information, but I prefer to use the second case that is calling jtextarea from main class and on jtxtarea the rectangle to be drawn. Can you tell something  about this case.

Comment: You can see in method 'postInitGUI()' of class 'GraphicsEx1', its text area 'jTextArea1' is referred to class 'DisplayItems' which extends to JTextArea. I 've done this bcoz I thought I can easily draw rectangle on jtextarea

Comment: The problem is, I can think of three ways to achieve what you want...directly via `paintComponent`, the glass pane or `JLayer`, each has it's merits and pitfalls depending on what you want to achieve...

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer for your info, but still I think there is another way,but it is correct or not I dont know. I tried a lot and finnaly I use a jpanel.Please check it out and reply me;

Comment: 1. Don't override the `paint` method of Swing components, apart from the fact that you're removing any double buffering support Swing provides, it's normally to high in the paint chain.  2. You MUST call `super.paintXxx` - the paint method is responsible for painting the content and children of the component, failing to do so will result in (normally) empty component...it also messes with the internals of Swing and events ;)

Answer (score 0):

*** Using jPanel ***

using jpanel, the graphics elements can be drawn;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GraphicsEx1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private JScrollPane jsp1;
private JTextArea jta1;
private JPanel jpnl1;

{
//Set Look & Feel
try {
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
} catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
GraphicsEx1 inst = new GraphicsEx1();
inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
inst.setVisible(true);
}

public GraphicsEx1() {
super();
initGUI();
postInitGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
try {
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
getContentPane().setLayout(null);
{
jsp1 = new JScrollPane();
getContentPane().add(jsp1);
jsp1.setBounds(10, 32, 372, 223);
{
jpnl1 = new JPanel();    //<----------------
jsp1.setViewportView(jpnl1);    //<----------------
jpnl1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
jpnl1.setLayout(null);
//jpnl1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(359, 327));
}
}
pack();
setSize(400, 300);
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void postInitGUI(){
frmGrpView gp=new frmGrpView();
jta1=new JTextArea();
jta1=gp;
jta1.setBounds(0,0, 336, 197);
jta1.setVisible(true);
//jpnl1.setBounds(0, 0, 336, 197);
jpnl1.add(jta1);    //<----------------
jpnl1.revalidate();
jsp1.revalidate();
}
}
//----------------------- Second Class --------------------------
class frmGrpView extends JTextArea{
public frmGrpView() {
super();
setEditable(false);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
super.paint(g);
g.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Overriding `paint` is not recommeded, as you remove any double buffering support that Swing components provide and it's generally to high in the paint chain. 2. This will draw a rectangle OVER the text - which might be what the OP is after, but it's worth pointing out ;)