# JLabel and JTextArea not working

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextarea

I am making a window that has a large text area and a small text area under it. This is what i have so far:

[image]

This is the code I have for it:

```
JPanel window=new JPanel(){
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon("textEffect.png");
        Image i=ii.getImage();
        g.drawImage(i,0,0,null,this);
    }
};
JLabel label=new JLabel("Say: ");
JTextArea dialog=new JTextArea(20,50);
JTextArea input=new JTextArea(1,46);
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(
    dialog,
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
);

//main method
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Window();
}
//Makes window and starts bot
public Window(){
    super("Pollockoraptor");
    setSize(600,400);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setEditable(false);
    dialog.setOpaque(false);
    dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    dialog.setLineWrap(true);
    input.addKeyListener(this);
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    window.add(scroll);
    window.add(label);
    window.add(input);
    window.setBackground(new Color(97,118,131));
    add(window);
    setVisible(true);
}'
```

How do I make the larger textarea partially transparent so I can see the background and how do I move "Say:" to be infront of the smaller textarea?

Comment: I really can't help yet without seeing your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first, but some unrelated suggestions: 1) don't read images in in a paintComponent method as you're unnecessarily re-reading the image and slowing down a method that has to be absolutely blindingly fast. Also, 2) never add a KeyListener to a text component, and I don't care that the Swing tutorials show this, it's just a dangerous thing to do, and there are much better ways of trapping input in a text component. 3) Your layout managers should help you position your components for you.

Comment: Oh and 4) follow MadProgrammer's advice as he knows Swing backwards and forwards.

Comment: `JTextArea input=new JTextArea(1,46);` should probably be `JTextField input=new JTextField(46);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default.  You'll want to change the layout manager, personally, I'd recommend something like `GridBagLayout`, but that's just me.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

To make the `JTextArea` see through, you're going to have to make the `JScrollPane` and it's `JViewPort` transparent as well.

Swing only knows how to paint fully opaque or fully transparent components.  You can create a translucent effect by making the component transparent and overriding it's `paintComponent` method and using an `AlphaComposite` or painting a with a `Color` which has an `alpha` value set to something below `255`

For example...

- [Can not draw image on JTextArea background when using Nimbus Look And Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879079/can-not-draw-image-on-jtextarea-background-when-using-nimbus-look-and-feel/17879790#17879790)
- [JTextArea not selectable, but still showing a "ghost" cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329310/jtextarea-not-selectable-but-still-showing-a-ghost-cursor/14329538#14329538)
- [Swing Graphics on JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152491/swing-graphics-on-jframe/14152568#14152568)

And general advice...

- [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`
- Override `getPreferredSize` of your custom component to get better results when been laid out
- Use `JFrame#pack` over `setSize`, this will calculate the window size based on the needs of the content and take into account the window frame decorations as well

Comment: Thank you, I used GridBagLayout and that aligned everything perfectly. I made the JViewPort transparent and fixed my background issue aswell.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I make the larger textarea partially transparent so I can see the background

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for problems when using a transparent background and a general purpose solution you can use to you don't need to do custom painting all the time.