# Get the background color of a component under any substance skin

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, substance

I'm using Swing and Substance library to change the look and feel of my application, I need the content pane (main `JPanel`) and a `JTextArea` to have the same background color regardless of the skin selected, I tried to change the color of the text area to be the color of the content pane when initializing it but under some skins (the MagmaSkin for example) the colors are different.

Comment: Make them transparent

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how do I make them transparent?

Comment: Transparent `JTextArea` for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879079/can-not-draw-image-on-jtextarea-background-when-using-nimbus-look-and-feel/17879790#17879790), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329310/jtextarea-not-selectable-but-still-showing-a-ghost-cursor/14329538#14329538), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152491/swing-graphics-on-jframe/14152568#14152568), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531992/make-background-image-show-through-panels-on-top/43532093#43532093)

Comment: I would, personally, tend towards changing the UI defaults so that the `JTextArea` and `JPanel` shared the same values. I've not used substance, but if it's anything like Nimbus, it's ... annoying ...

Comment: Late reply since I don't really monitor SO questions that much. Take a look at setColorizationFactor APIs available in the SubstanceCortex class. These will allow you to control the amount of colorization applied to the background of your components. For additional questions it would be much easier to get in touch over at https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance